# Multiple child and parent form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, parent-child

I have 6 forms (Let just say F1,F2,F2a,F2b,F2c,F2d)

I'm trying to make **F2a** - **F2d** as childs of **F2** while **F2** parentform is **F1** and **F1** child form is **F2**

what i've tried

**F1**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     F2 nX = new F2(this);

     this.Visible = false;

     nX.Visible = true;
}
```

**F2**

```
public F2(F1 parentForm)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.oF = parentForm;

    F2a nA = new F2a(this); //It give me error as i will describe down there.
}

public F1 oF;
```

**F2a** - **F2d**

```
    public F2* (F2 parentForm) //Well lets just say * stand for the letter of each Form
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.oF = parentForm;
    }
    public F2 oF;
```

On the **F2** it gives me 2 error

1.The best overloaded method match for 'GUI_X.F2a.F2a(System.Windows.Forms.F2)' has some invalid arguments

2.Argument 1: cannot convert from 'GUI_X.F2' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu'

So why it isn't work for **F2** to **F2a** - **F2d** while it's work for **F1** to **F2** ?
am i wrong put something ?How i can resolve this ?

I'm new to C# and i will be grateful if someone could help me and explain it as easy as possible.

And if this help i'm using **Windows Form** project.

Thankyou in Advance.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry,i'm forgot to initialize **oF** in the F2*'s,Thanks to @S_I_R answer.
But still it won't resolve the problem

Comment: Looks like a type mismatch. Does `this.oF` need to be a `base` `System.Windows.Form` or a custom base type?

Comment: Can you include all of the class definitions into your question? I.e `public class F2 : baseclass`

Comment: @sayse 

**F1** `public partial class F1 : Form`

,**F2** `public partial class F2 : Form`

,F2a - F2d same as **F2** followed by their letter

Comment: Well what the two errors are saying is that the `F2A` contructor expects a `MainMenu` as the parameter, I assume you have a second contructor such as `public F2A(MainMenu mm)` and it is thinking that you are trying to use this, You may find success in reorganising your constructors so that the form constructor is first followed by the menu one, and then choosing clean solution, followed by build solution

Comment: Well there is something i didn't realize before,i found that VS could make stub constructor (Though i still don't know about that) and its resolve my problem.
Thanks all for the helps,i'm **Ultimately** new to C# and VS.

Comment: No worries, we're all still learning :)

Answer (score 2):

Would you please verify the type of this.oF as F2 in F2* classes

```
public F2* (F2 parentForm) 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.oF = parentForm;
}
private F2 oF; //Make sure this is F2 not F1 or other
```

**EDIT:**

Just declare F2a-F2d private object in F2 class then when needed just show them

```
public class F2
{
  private F2a f2a;
  private F2b f2b;
  public F1 oF; 
  public F2(F1 parent)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.oF = parent;
    f2a = new F2a(this);
    f2b = new F2b(this);
  }

// Now you call F2a - F2d from any method
public void ShowF2a()
{ 
  f2a.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: on **F2** `public F1 oF` , 
on **F2a - F2d** `public F2 oF` , 
I think there is no problem with that.My problem is how i can make F2a to F2d become the childs of Form F2 while F1 is the parent of F2,So i could call F2a,F2b,etc from F2

Answer (score 0):

You existing code should look like gthis:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     F2 nX = new F2(this);
     nX.Show();
}
```

..but make one more change and you'll have what you want:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     F2 nX = new F2(this);
     nX.ShowDialog();
}
```

You need to call Show on the form instance to make it show up. However, if you call ShowModal it will not let you back into the 'parent' until you close the child.

Comment: When i change *Visible* into *ShowModal* it gives me an error that say that there no refrence for *ShowModal*
Should i add a refrence or there is something wrong with my VS ?

Comment: Apologies - it should have been ShowDialog. I've edited the answer to match.

Answer (score 0):

You have put one part of your form `F2` into the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. Don't do this. Put all parts of the form in your own namespace (`GUI_X`). Check all the files which contain `partial class F2` and make sure the namespace is correct.